# Energy stored in capacitors connected in series

Tags: energy, supercapacitor

I am confused with calculating total energy stored in capacitors connected in series. 
To calculate a energy stored in a single capacitor in terms of joules is `C(V*V)/2`. I want to connect `2.5V` `500Farad` capacitance of `20 capacitors` in series to a `48 Volt` source.  so Total energy stored is equal to 
`500(48*48)/2` or 
`20(500(2.5*2.5)/2)`? 
Which one is correct?

Answer (score 5):

Even without knowing the formula for energy in a capacitor the answer is simple: 20 times the energy stored in one capacitor. Conservation of energy rules.

The problem with your first formula is that the total capacitance of N capacitors C in series is not C but C / N.

Answer (score 1):

For series connection of capacitor,

1. find `C_total` using equation

   `c_total = 1/((1/c1) + (1/c2) + . . . . + (1/c20))`

as you have identical capacitor 20, `c_total = c/20`

2. find `energy`,

   `E_series = (1/2) x c_total x (2V)^2`

In case of parallel, 
`C_total = c1 + c2 + .... + c20`

for your case it is 
`C_total = 20 x C`, and

```
`E_parallel = (1/2) x C_total x V^2`
```

Answer (score 0):

Okeyy. I am a little dusty but let's see..Capacitors are nothing more than complex impedance (Reactance) :
$$
Z = 1/jωC = -j/ωC = -j/2πfC$$
When you have resistors in series you do : \$ R_s = R_1+R_2 + R_3 + ... \$

Likewise the overall impedance if capacitors are put in series is:
$$
Z_s = Z_1 + Z_2 + ... =  {-j*20\over 2πfC} =20*Z
$$
Since the capacitors are all the same, the voltage across each one of them will be the same (voltage drop will be the same since impedance is the same and Kirchhoff Voltage law is true). So, you actually have a voltage divider for each one of them : 
$$
V_c = {Z \over Z_s}*V_{in} = {Vin\over20}
$$
Now it's simple.
$$
Ε_s = \sum{1\over2}C_i*V_i = 20 *{1\over2}C*V_c = {{1\over2}C*V_{in}^2\over20}
$$
I see that this is not equal to the energy stored in one capacitor. I believe that is because of the non-linearity capacitors introduce to the system and the way they trigger AC current. Afterall, we just measure the STORED energy, not the overall energy. Maybe I am wrong, but I cannot seem to find an error in my logic. Critique is welcome.

Comment: [Welcome to EE.SE!](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour)! This is not an answer to the question. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.  Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: I think your equation is ok but summary voltage on series capacitor is twenty times bigger than simple one, so Vin is equal 20 x 2.5V = 50V. Accident capacity of series capacitors i equal lowest capacitance of any connected capacitor.